# How to do partial parse xml in JAXB with validation?

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb, xsd

I have a big XML file which I want to validation against an XSD. But from the big xml file I only want just one element

This is my example XML

```
<Something>
  <Element1>element</Element1>
  <IDontWantThis>element</IDontWantThis>
<Something>
```

And this is my POJO so I didn't include IDontWantThis

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Something")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Something {

    @XmlElement(name = "Element1")
    private String element1;

}
```

And this is how I parse my XML

```
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(filePath);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File(XSD));

        Unmarshaller u = JAXBContext.newInstance(Something.class).createUnmarshaller();
        u.setSchema(schema);
        u.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
        Products products = u.unmarshal(source, Something.class).getValue();
```

But I got this error when I run my application

```
unexpected element (uri:"urn:blah", local:"IDontWantThis"). Expected elements are <{urn:blah}Element1>,<{urn:blah}Element1>
```

How do I just parse partial element, because my xml is quite big and contains a lot of elements I don't really need to use.

Comment: change your schema to accommodate [anyelement](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyValidationEventHandler` is a class you have written to custom hand errors.  If you want to ignore an error you just need to put the logic there.

Comment: but I don't want to ignore the error I just don't want to parse the element that I'm not going to use.

Comment: @toy - You will need to return true from the `handleEvent` method in your implementation of `ValidationEventHandler` to continue with the parse.  You can hold onto the `ValidationEvent` and report any errors you want at the end.